Как подвинуть только правую сторону border
У меня есть border, который при изменении width меняет размер справа и слева.
Мне нужно что бы текст с border плавно выплывал из IMG, для этого надо как то его разширить только вправо, что что бы левая сторона оставалась на месте, border-right-width не работает
сейчас код показывает img и сзади него идет border в нем текст с номером телефона, это готовый вариант, нужно что бы такой был при наведении, а изначально был только img без border'а сзади
Надеюсь понятно


body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #121212;
}

.Header {
  display: flex;
  border: 3px solid #292929;
  height: 85px;
  background: #292929;
  color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  clear: both;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 1.5em;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 1.5em;
}

.logot {
  display: inherit;
  margin-right: 1%;
}

.headH1 {
  display: inherit;
  margin-right: 25%;
}

.buttonHeader {
  margin-left: 25%;
  padding: 0.5em 2em;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: none;
  transition: 0.2s;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.imgPhone1 {
  border: 2px solid #00fbff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #00fbff;
  border-width: 1px;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.numberOfPhone {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 10%;
  border: 0px solid #00696b;
  color: white;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
  width: 145px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: #00696b;
  border-width: 12.9px;
}

.buttonHeader:hover {
  padding: 0.5em 2em;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  background-color: #00fbff;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
<div class="Header">
  <img src="Img/logo.png" height="50px" class="logot">
  <h1 class="headH1">My-Giro</h1>
  <img src="Img/phone__1.svg" height="40px" class="imgPhone1">
  <span class="numberOfPhone">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;+7 (999) 999 99-99</span>
  <button class="buttonHeader">Заказать звонок</button>
</div>



Нужно двигать бордер у span

При твоих стилях не видно чтобы border-width менялся справа и слева - он и изначально 0px, и по наведению вообще отключается (none). А в целом, есть свойство border-right-width.

@yar85, он, видимо, имеет в виду не ширину границы, а паддинг справа

Да, понятно что ничего не понятно... Автор, добавь в вопрос (не в комменты) больше подробностей, пожалуйста.

Сейчас добавлю )

не могу найти где его изменить

Готово, изменил

Если ширину спан автоматическая то так не получиться?

все тоже самое за исключением нескольких моментов


header {
    width:100%; 
    height:5rem; 
    background-color: black; 
    display: flex; 
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    color: white;
    }
    .logo {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    }
.phone {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    width: 30rem;
    position: relative;
}
.buttonHeader {position: absolute; right: 1rem;}
.phone img, .numberOfPhone {position: absolute;}
.phone img {z-index: 2;}
.numberOfPhone {z-index: 1; width: 0; left: 0; opacity: 0; border:1px solid red;}
.buttonHeader:hover ~ .numberOfPhone {overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; animation: scale 1s linear; animation-fill-mode: forwards;}
@keyframes scale {
0% {width: 0px; left: 0; opacity: 0;}
100% {opacity: 1; width:200px; opacity: 1; overflow: hidden; }    
}
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="Img/logo.png" height="50px" class="logot">
            <h1 class="headH1">My-Giro</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="phone">
            <img src="Img/phone__1.svg" height="40px" class="imgPhone1">        
            <div class="buttonHeader">Заказать звонок</div>
            <span class="numberOfPhone">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;+7 (999) 999 99-99</span>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>




Спасибо большое :D

Все работает, но потому что flex-directon: row, я не понимаю как каритинку и номер расположить по центру(с адаптивностью)

По центру чего? горизонтали вертикали или по центру header?

по горизонтали !

у класса .phone заменить width на 50%

у меня получилось следующее, переделал верстку немного и css но смысл должен быть понятен


header {
    width:100%; 
    height:5rem; 
    background-color: black; 
    display: flex; 
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    color: white;
    }
    .logo {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    }
.phone {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    width: 30rem;
    position: relative;
}
.buttonHeader {position: absolute; right: 1rem;}
.phone img, .numberOfPhone {position: absolute;}
.phone img {z-index: 2;}
.numberOfPhone {z-index: 1; opacity: 0; left: -5rem;}
.buttonHeader:hover ~ .numberOfPhone {opacity: 1; transform: translateX(5rem);}
    <header>
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="Img/logo.png" height="50px" class="logot">
            <h1 class="headH1">My-Giro</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="phone">
            <img src="Img/phone__1.svg" height="40px" class="imgPhone1">        
            <div class="buttonHeader">Заказать звонок</div>
            <span class="numberOfPhone">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;+7 (999) 999 99-99</span>
        </div>
    </header>




Видимо вы не правильно поняли, есть img с классом Phone1, и при наведении на него справа от него должен плавно выплывать номер телефона

типо из картинки выплывает номер телефона и border вместе с ним
